# APEX error on trigger

Tags: trigger

```
trigger quotepotential on Quote_Line_Item__c (after insert) {
    list<batch__c> b=[select batch_value__c 
                      from batch__c 
                      order by batch_value__c DESC LIMIT 1];
    if(!b.isempty()){
        list<Quote_Line_Item__c> quotelineitem=new list<Quote_Line_Item__c>();
        for(Quote_Line_Item__c quoteline:trigger.new){
            quoteline.max_batch__c=b.batch_value__c;
            quotelineitem.add(quoteline);
        }
    }
}
```

Help me to find out get rid of this error

Comment: Please be more specific, where in code you get the error?

Comment: What is the error can also help

Answer (score 5):

In your code, `b` is a list, not a single sobject. Either use `Batch__c b = [...]` or use `b[0]` further in code.