# APEX Trigger on the updati

Tags: apex

```
 trigger quotepotential on Quote_Line_Item__c (after insert) {
    list<batch__c> b=[select batch_value__c from batch__c  ORDER BY  batch_value__c DESC LIMIT 1];
  if(!b.isempty()){
      list<Quote_Line_Item__c> quotelineitem=new list<Quote_Line_Item__c>();
        for(Quote_Line_Item__c quoteline:trigger.new){
                  quoteline.max_batch__c=b.batch_value__c;
                  quotelineitem.add(quoteline);
             }
    }
}
```

: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST at line 6 column 24

Comment: dont put duplicate questions please .Post only once .Welcome to stackexchange salesforce !

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17977/apex-error-on-trigger.I think this is the duplicate question